# How does Free-Hand work with Titan Mauler?

Tags: weapons, barbarian, pathfinder-2e, oversized-weapons

I am a small or medium Giant Instinct Barbarian with a large Free-Hand weapon, such as a large gauntlet. How does the Free-Hand trait work with the Titan Mauler ability?

The [Titan Mauler](https://2e.aonprd.com/Instincts.aspx?ID=4) ability states:

> You can use a weapon built for a Large creature if you are Small or Medium (both normally and when raging). If you're not Small or Medium, you can use a weapon built for a creature one size larger than you. You gain access to this larger weapon, of any weapon type otherwise available at character creation. It has the normal Price and Bulk for a weapon of its size. **When wielding such a weapon in combat, increase your additional damage from Rage from 2 to 6, but you have the clumsy 1 condition because of the weapon's unwieldy size. You can't remove this clumsy condition or ignore its penalties by any means while wielding the weapon.**

Whereas the [Free-Hand](https://2e.aonprd.com/Traits.aspx?ID=181) trait states:

> This weapon doesn’t take up your hand, usually because it is built into your armor. A free-hand weapon can’t be Disarmed. You can use the hand covered by your free-hand weapon to wield other items, perform manipulate actions, and so on. You can’t attack with a free-hand weapon if you’re wielding anything in that hand or otherwise using that hand. **When you’re not wielding anything and not otherwise using the hand, you can use abilities that require you to have a hand free as well as those that require you to be wielding a weapon in that hand.** Each of your hands can have only one free-hand weapon on it.

To my reading I never wield a Free-Hand weapon, I am just able to use abilities that require me to wield a weapon, but is Titan Mauler one such ability? The Titan Mauler doesn't have a proper ["requirements" entry](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=65) like feats do because it is an Instinct Ability, but on the other hand it basically does nothing unless I wield a large weapon.

Moreover, when does a large Free-Hand weapon such as a gauntlet cause me to be clumsy?

Answer (score 3):

> To my reading, I never wield a Free-Hand weapon.

I would argue that is an incorrect interpretation (although I will admit this isn't the clearest case in the world). Breaking down the [Free-Hand](https://2e.aonprd.com/Traits.aspx?ID=181) trait:

> This weapon **doesn't take up your hand**... You can use the hand **covered by your free-hand weapon to *wield* other items**

So, interestingly, it's not that your Free-Hand weapon isn't *wielded*, but that it doesn't take up your hand's capacity to wield other things. The text never explicitly states that Free-Hand weapons aren't wielded; in fact, by saying that we can "wield other items" in that hand, it implies that we are wielding some item already (which would be the Free-Hand weapon). This should inform the context of the rest of the description, with the later mentions of "wielding anything *in* that hand" and "wielding anything" supposed to refer to the previously mentioned ability to "wield other items" in that hand.

Thus, [Titan Mauler](https://2e.aonprd.com/Instincts.aspx?ID=4) would always be in effect in combat, so you'd be clumsy whether or not you were wielding another weapon in that hand, since you are still wielding the Free-Hand weapon, despite being unable to attack with it.